# Remove width and height from gallery images in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery

I am in the process of modifying a WP installation.

I am using a modified Gallery shortcode to display the galleries, and a filter to remove width and height parameters which is required in order to keep pages responsive.

My problem is that the galleries display properly when I link to an attachment page (the default). However when I link the thumbnail to a file the width and height parameters aren't removed by the filter.

This is the filter:

```
/** remove gallery height and width*/
add_image_size( 'my_gallery_shortcode', 200, 120, true );

add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link', 'remove_img_width_height', 10, 4);

function remove_img_width_height( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id, $post_thumbnail) {
if ($post_thumbnail=='my_gallery_shortcode'){
$html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );
}
return $html;
}

/** END remove gallery height and width*/
```

This is the custom gallery code:

```
/** custom gallery code */

add_shortcode('gallery', 'my_gallery_shortcode');    
function my_gallery_shortcode($attr) {
    $post = get_post();

static $instance = 0;
$instance++;

if ( ! empty( $attr['ids'] ) ) {
    // 'ids' is explicitly ordered, unless you specify otherwise.
    if ( empty( $attr['orderby'] ) )
        $attr['orderby'] = 'post__in';
    $attr['include'] = $attr['ids'];
}

// Allow plugins/themes to override the default gallery template.
$output = apply_filters('post_gallery', '', $attr);
if ( $output != '' )
    return $output;

// We're trusting author input, so let's at least make sure it looks like a valid orderby statement
if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
    $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
    if ( !$attr['orderby'] )
        unset( $attr['orderby'] );
}

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
    'id'         => $post->ID,
    'itemtag'    => 'dl',
    'icontag'    => 'dt',
    'captiontag' => 'dd',
    'columns'    => 3,
    'size'       => 'medium',
    'include'    => '',
    'exclude'    => ''
), $attr));

$id = intval($id);
if ( 'RAND' == $order )
    $orderby = 'none';

if ( !empty($include) ) {
    $_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );

    $attachments = array();
    foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
        $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
    }
} elseif ( !empty($exclude) ) {
    $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $exclude, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
} else {
    $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
}

if ( empty($attachments) )
    return '';

if ( is_feed() ) {
    $output = "\n";
    foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
        $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($att_id, $size, true) . "\n";
    return $output;
}

$itemtag = tag_escape($itemtag);
$captiontag = tag_escape($captiontag);
$icontag = tag_escape($icontag);
$valid_tags = wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' );
if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $itemtag ] ) )
    $itemtag = 'dl';
if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $captiontag ] ) )
    $captiontag = 'dd';
if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $icontag ] ) )
    $icontag = 'dt';

$columns = intval($columns);
$itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor(100/$columns) : 100;
$float = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

$selector = "gallery-{$instance}";

$gallery_style = $gallery_div = '';

$size_class = sanitize_html_class( $size );
$gallery_div = "<div id='$selector' class='gallery galleryid-{$id} gallery-columns-{$columns} gallery-size-{$size_class}'>";
$output = apply_filters( 'gallery_style', $gallery_style . "\n\t\t" . $gallery_div );

$i = 0;
foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
    $link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false);

    $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
    $output .= "
        <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon'>
            $link
        </{$icontag}>";
    if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
        $output .= "
            <{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
            " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
            </{$captiontag}>";
    }
    $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";

}

$output .= "
    </div>\n";

return $output;
}
```

Can anyone help ensure that gallery thumbnail images, in all sizes, are displayed without dimensions regardless of what they link to?

Comment: try debugging it by appending something to the `$html` in `remove_img_width_height` function and see if it works.

Comment: Can you clarify? What are you suggesting?

Comment: you save the result of the preg_replace in $html (this is in your `function remove_img_width_height`). For debugging purposes you can do `$html . 'test';` at line 9, before the closing bracket `}` and see if the conditional statement resulted in true

Comment: I'm not a wordpress connaisseur or anything, those are some basic practices when you're not sure if a block is executed or not.

Answer (score 0):

To make a responsive gallery you really dont need to remove all the height and weight tag from the IMG. All you need to do is add some css to you image tag.

For example:

```
<div class="facebook">
  <img src="http:///" height="100" width="100" >
```

To make this image responsive add this css

```
  div.facebook img
   { 
    width: 100%;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks but that won't work. The images are not all the same aspect ratio. They have to be limited by height or width - whichever is greater.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Problem when you add a Image with the **Gutenberg Blog Editor** use this css in your css file to set the width and height auto so there is no problem anymore:

```
figure > img {
width: auto;
height: auto;}
```

:-)